# (База GUI, Java) Как сделать видимым движение шара по панели, привязав старт к нажатию кнопки?

Tags: java, gui

```
int x = 70; // координаты для шара
int y = 70;
MyDrawPanel drawPanel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleAnimation gui = new SimpleAnimation();
    gui.go();
}

public void go() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

    JButton button = new JButton("Запустить шарик");
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
    button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener2());

    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.gray);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
    }
}

class ButtonListener2 implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText("Шарик запущен!");

        // Если вставлять метод таким образом, то видно только конечное положение шара, но не его перемещение по панели
        moveBall();
    }
}

private void moveBall() {
    // Перемещение шара по панели

    for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++) {
        x++;
        y++;
        drawPanel.repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Анимацию надо делать в отдельном потоке!

Comment: Работает, спасибо! 
До потоков пока не дошел, но скоро

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ButtonListener2 implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText("Шарик запущен!");

        new Thread(() -> moveBall()).start();
    }
}
```